# Ignore in assertion dialog is disabled in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, exception, visual-studio-2015, assert

I am coding in C++ using Visual Studio 2015 Professional (update 3).

My problem is: When an assert() is triggered the assertion dialog did not pop up any more! Instead the exception dialog opens.

It looks like all asserts will be handled as exceptions.

I have re-installed the whole Visual Studio 2015 IDE, disabled all extensions, resetted my settings, etc. But it seems there is one setting stored in the registry that changed the assertion behaviour.

How do I bring back the assertion dialog?

Comment: Assuming this is true, something tells me following the `assert` macro will probably lead you to the culprit. Out of curiosity, the behavior you're describing isn't mentioned in [the VS2015 `assert` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9sb57dw4.aspx). What *exactly* does the exception thrown actually equate with, and how did you conclude `assert` was causing it? Did you just make a simple one-liner with `assert(0);`, compiled *without* `NDEBUG` defined, and caught an exception?

Comment: This problem only occurs on my company pc. I am not sure when it was introduced, maybe a few weeks ago when I upgraded Azure as suggested by the IDE. This bevaviour did not occur on the computers of my workmates.
If assert(false) is triggered in Debug, the exception dialog pops up on my system, not the assertion dialog where I could ignore the assert.

And in this exception dialog the ignore button is disabled, and that is the main problem for me at the moment.

Maybe a C++ runtime package is wrong, I don't know. That was the reason I re-installed the whole IDE with deinstalling all first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace following ucrtbased.dll with version 10.0.10240

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbased.dll  //32bit 10.0.14393 (not ok)

C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbased.dll  //64bit 10.0.14393 (not ok)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Now, I have got my assertion dialog back :)
Although the version of these DLLs were 10.0.10240 on my system (at least properties say so) I replaced them from another system and everything is working fine.

Comment: Thanks, its working for me too. my problem started after installing visual studio 2017 that Installer got stuck applying Win10SDK_10.0.14393.795.